# Can an abstract class be used as a functional specification

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface, specifications

I'm working on a toy project with my teammate for the purpose of learning new technics like object pool.

Then I find it complicated when it comes to referencing other scripts like the example below.

So I come up with the idea of using an abstract class as a functional specification to let other scripts know that this function exists.

This is an example of one script being referenced

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
         // take damage and if hp below 0, die
    }
}
```

This is an example of one script referencing other scripts

What it does is to get an 'enemy' script from RandomGameObject (no matter how it is detected) and call TakeDamage() function to give damage

```
//somewhere in another script
enemy EnemyScript = RandomGameObject.GetComponent<enemy>();
EnemyScript.TakeDamage(5);
```

The problem is that if my teammate works on the 'enemy' class and I need to call the function that is expected to be there.

There is simply no way to do that other than just waiting for my teammates.

This is a huge waste of time.

It's just a small toy project though, I can simply implement both.

But I believe that there should be some cases where it doesn't go that easy in the real task.

Here is how I fixed this problem

First, write an abstract class that has all the necessary functions in it

```
public abstract class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void TakeDamage(int damage);
}
```

Second, reference abstract class

```
//somewhere in another script
enemy EnemyScript = RandomGameObject.GetComponent<enemy>();
EnemyScript.TakeDamage(5);
```

Third, actually implement class

```
public class creeper : enemy
{
    private int hp = 100;
    public override void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
         // take damage and if hp below 0, die
         Explode();
    }
    public void Explode()
    {
        // give damage to any entity in 3 meter radius
    }
}
```

If my knowledge about inheritance is correct, this will benefit every teammate and enhance productivity.

Is my idea a proper way to solve this problem?
Or there is a better way to cooperate?

Comment: Interfaces are made for that...do I miss anything, maybe?

Comment: oh i missed about interfaces. thank you for telling me that. but how to you think about its concept? can writing interface prevent such situation?

Comment: if I understood well your problem, then interfaces are the very best choice. An "interface" is a contract between parts. They also decouples the parts, so they can implemented in a full independent way.  I'd sit with your mate to design the necessary interfaces, which COULD be placed in a dedicated library (it very depends on how your project is structured). At that point, each one can develop its section freely. Also, bear in mind that interfaces help the testing: you could write a surrogate of that your mate is doing, as implementation of an interface.

Comment: And, interfaces provide a path to pluggable components. You specify the interfaces you components must implement and what interfaces they should call for services. Put all that in an independent assembly (DLL). With that, all actors in your system can take a dependency on that assembly and develop at these own speed

Comment: And, a class can implement many interfaces but only derive from one abstract parent class. Btw. You should consider typical c# naming conventions. Last point: if you have a shared interface/ contracts project, you may even consider making it a nuget on a private feed, so you can safely version it.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods would be a bit overkill for a small project - just make a first commit only with the interface -> everyone can branch of and use the interface or implement it

Comment: @derHugo that was more like a "far future" suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on this question.

If you only need to specify the signature of the `TakeDamage()` function, then you can use an interface. An interface is a contract that specifies the behaviour of a function, but it does not specify how the function should be implemented.

An abstract class is a good choice if you also need to specify the behaviour of the `TakeDamage()` function. An abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated, it but can be inherited from. This means that you can create a subclass of the abstract class and implement the `TakeDamage()` function in any way you want.

The main difference between an interface and an abstract class is that an interface can only specify the signature of the function, while an abstract class can specify both the signature and the behaviour of the function.

Using an interface or an abstract class is a matter of personal preference. You and your teammate can agree on which one to use based on your specific needs.

Here are some of the benefits of using an interface:

- It promotes loose coupling between classes.
- It allows for greater flexibility in terms of implementation.
- It simplifies testing.
- It promotes code reusability.

Comment: Of course you can have interfaces _and_ a suite of test cases any implementation of that interface needs to pass, if you want to enforce behavioral contracts. But that is a project agreement not inherent to the technology.